# Determine cycle from adjacency matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Is there a way/algorithm to determine if there is a cycle in a graph if I only have the adjacency matrix and can not visualize the graph?

Comment: You can still depth-first search with an adjacency matrix.

Comment: Warning: the (top two) answers at the stackoverflow link @Travis pointed to are wrong. Basically, they are confusing "closed walk" (repeated vertices allowed) with "cycle".

Answer (score 5):

Let the vertices of $G$ be labelled $v_1,\ldots,v_n$, and the adjacency matrix of $G$ be $A$ with row/column $i$ of $A$ correspond to $v_i$.

If you want a purely linear algebraic approach (albeit non-constructive), consider $L=D-A$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with $(D)_{i,i}=\deg(v_i)$. This matrix is called the [Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) matrix of $G$. A basic fact is that the number of times zero appears as an eigenvalue of $L$, i.e., $n-\text{rank}(L)$, is the number of connected components of $G$.

> *Claim*: $G$ is acyclic if and only if $\text{trace}(L)=2\text{rank}(L).$
>
> Equivalently, $G$ has a cycle if and only if $$\text{trace}(L)\geq2(\text{rank}(L)+1).$$

*Proof*: $G$ is acyclic if and only if it is a forest, i.e., $G$ has $c$ components and exactly $n-c=\text{rank}(L)$ edges. On the other hand, by the Handshaking Lemma we have $|E(G)|=\frac{1}{2}\text{trace}(L)$. The claim follows.

Comment: Do you have a book reference for this, in case one wants to refer to this result?

Comment: @stackExchangeUser No, I just deduced it myself. But It wouldn't surprise me if it was an exercise buried in some old textbook.

Comment: This only applies to undirected graphs right? The n - c edges argument would only work if the graph is undirected

Comment: @Jasper yes this is for undirected graphs.