# If a distance matrix is that of a weighted tree

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, trees

I am given a distance matrix of size $n \times n$. I need to determine if it can represent a weighted tree or not.

Comment: Are all weights positive?

Comment: [this approach](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910931/determine-cycle-from-adjacency-matrix/911040#911040) seems useful

Comment: The problem amounts to checking whether the associated adjacency matrix corresponds to a graph that is both connected and cycle-free.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom A adjacency matrix is different from distance matrix.

Comment: Yes, but you can get the adjacency matrix (or Laplacian matrix) by setting all non-zero weights to one.

Comment: Ok. remember that even if there is no u-v edge, the distance between them is non-zero and therefore just setting the non-zero weights to one will give me negation of identity matrix.

Comment: My mistake. Given a picture like the one [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix#Examples_and_uses), would there be a canonical way to decide if the picture "can represent a weighted tree"?

Comment: One thing I thought was of was that for each row i, find the column j such that weight[i][j] is minimum in that row. I can claim that there must be an edge between i and j. This way I can identify minimum of n/2 edges since the same edge can be repeated when I'm checking for row=j. I'm not sure how to proceed further.